# AS3 webcam stream tutorial request

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

can anybody tell me where can i find some tutorials/ sample code on how to stream a webcam using ActionScript 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for tutorials about the Camera class.  Here's a pretty good one from the looks of it:

www.communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=2816A

If you're streaming you're probably streaming to Flash Media Server or Red5, Wowza, etc.  You'd do well to visit fmsguru.com and flashcomguru.com to read the tutorials there.  Flash Player 10 also now supports direct client to client streaming and Adobe's also got the new Flash Collaboration Service which provides some of the functionality of FMS.  There's an Adobe blog post here:

http://blogs.adobe.com/collabmethods/2008/12/try_rtmfp_and_clienttoclient_d.html